# Преобразование списка в арифметическое выражение

Tags: python, list, форматирование, арифметика, decimal

я новичек, возникла проблема, уже весь мозг сломался.

На входе у меня есть список:
['3', '+', '0.34', '-', '3', '*', '0.051651', '/', '7', '+', '1.201E+3']

На выходне мне нужно получить запись следующего вида, чтобы она рассчиталась:
x = Decimal('3') + Decimal('0.34') - Decimal ('3') * Decimal('0.051651') / Decimal('7') + Decimal('1.201E+3')

Ожидается, что если напишу Print(x) вернется результат арифметических действий

Помогите, пожалуйста, не понимаю как отформатировать список в арифметическое выражение. Спасибо заранее

Comment: `eval(''.join(['3', '+', '0.34', '-', '3', '*', '0.051651', '/', '7', '+', '1.201E+3']))`

Comment: Спасибо, но так пробовал. Нужно именно чтобы использовался Decimal для большей точности, потому что 0.1+0.1+0.1 дает 0.30000000000000004. Округлять нельзя

Comment: Тогда сделайте `list(map(lambda x: x if x in '+-/*' else Decimal(x), a))` и используйте https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation

Comment: [Decimal('3'), '+', Decimal('0.34'), '-', Decimal('3'), '*', Decimal('0.051651'), '/', Decimal('7'), '+', Decimal('1201')]  Получится такой список, но как можно потом этот список преобразовать именно в выражение...

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
a=['3', '+', '0.34', '-', '3', '*', '0.051651', '/', '7', '+', '1.201E+3']
b='print('
for i in a:
    b+=i
b+=')'
exec(b)
```

Все значения списка `a` перебираются и добавляются в *строку* `b`. Ваше выражение хранится в переменной `b`, функция `exec` может выполнять функцию *из строки*, в данном случае из строки `b`.

Comment: Спасибо. Строку я понимаю как посчитать, уже три способа нашел. А как именно прикрутить туда Decimal в расчет, пока все еще нет понимания...

Comment: Но главное результат посчитала) Я ещё подумаю

Answer (score 0):

Пришлось небольшой парсер написать, но уверен, что задача решается в три строчки на самом деле.

```
#строка с любыми арифметическими действиями
b = '65465.046546*65465-35184'

#с помощью регулярный выражений разбивка
d2 = re.split(r'((?:[+-]?\d+(?:\.\d*)?|\.\d+)(?:[eE][-+]?\d+)?)',b)
#избавляюсь от пустот
d3 = list(filter(None, d2))

summarizer = Decimal('0')

for i in d3:
print('начало цикла')
if '*' in d3:
    superindex = d3.index('*')
    left = d3[(superindex - 1)]
    right = d3[(superindex + 1)]
    result = Decimal(left) * Decimal(right)
    del d3[superindex]
    del d3[superindex]
    d3[(superindex - 1)] = str(result)

elif '/' in d3:
    superindex = d3.index('/')
    left = d3[(superindex - 1)]
    right = d3[(superindex + 1)]
    result = Decimal(left) / Decimal(right)
    del d3[superindex]
    del d3[superindex]
    d3[(superindex - 1)] = str(result)

 for j in d3:
  summarizer += Decimal(j)

  print('summarizer',summarizer)
```

---

PS Извиняюсь за неубранность в коде, но главное суть.